# Button not rendering where expected

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table, createelement

I am clicking a button in my HTML and expecting a table to be created with X amount of rows depending on the for loop and then at the end of each row a button.

I am expecting the output to look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> first element </td>
  <button> </button>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> first element </td>
  <button> </button>
 </tr>
</table>
```

However for some reason the button does not render on the first row:

```
  <table>
     <tr>
      <td> first element </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> first element </td>
      <button> </button>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
function makeHTMLMatchesTable(array){
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute("id", "unMatchButton");
  console.log(array.length, 'ARRAY');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      console.log(array[i], 'ai');
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.textContent = array[i];
      row.appendChild(cell);
      row.appendChild(button);
      table.appendChild(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting the output to look like this

The structure you quote is invalid. You can't have `button` as a direct child of `tr`. From [the spec for `tr`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element), the only things that can be in a `tr` element are `td`, `th`, or script-supporting elements.

> However for some reason the button does not render on the first row:

Because you've only created **one** `button` element, and then appended it to two separate rows. Appending it doesn't clone it, it *moves* it from its old parent (if any) to a new one.

To fix it:

1. Create a new `button` each time you want a new button (with a new `id`; `id` values **must** be unique in a document).
2. Append the `button` to a `td`, not to a `tr`.

Example:

```js
function makeHTMLMatchesTable(array) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.textContent = array[i];
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell = document.createElement('td');             // Second td
    var button = document.createElement('button');   // New button for each
    button.setAttribute("id", "unMatchButton" + i);  // Unique id
    cell.appendChild(button);                        // Button in cell
    row.appendChild(cell);                           // Add second cell
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  return table;
}
document.body.appendChild(
  makeHTMLMatchesTable(["one", "two", "three"])
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a new button for each row

```
function makeHTMLMatchesTable(array){
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  console.log(array.length, 'ARRAY');
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i], 'ai');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.textContent = array[i];
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute("id", "unMatchButton");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    row.appendChild(button);
    table.appendChild(row);
 }

return table;
```

}